# preg match end of word/line or not a digit

Tags: php, regex

How to match end of line/word or not a digit

## pattern

```
/\d{3}[\b\D]/
```

## match

```
123
123-
123 1abc
123a
```

## no match

```
1234
```

Comment: `\w` match both alpha, digit, underscore etc

Comment: Why isn't your last example a match? It has 3 digits `234` followed by the end of line.

Comment: @barmar, this is only the last part of a pattern

Comment: Sorry I noticed my mistake. Try this one `"/\d{3}[\D+|\s]/"` http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/gpD

Comment: @Andreas Why are you putting the alternatives inside `[]` rather than `()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match exactly 3 digits that aren't surrounded by any other digits, use negative lookarounds.

```
/(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)/
  ^           ^
lookbehind  lookahead
```

Lookarounds are explained at [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zE2qA8/1)

Comment: can you explain what the difference is between `?<!` and `?!` ?

Comment: One is a lookbehind, the other is a lookahead.

Comment: ok.. so it will match `\d{3}` first and then look behind (in the beginning of the pattern) ?

Comment: Exactly. A negative lookbehind means "it can't be preceded by X". A negative lookahead means "it can't be followed by X".

Comment: Thanks.. Please upvote my question.. I have unmotivated down votes :)

Comment: It's not a very well written question. Just listing a bunch of matches and non matches, with very little explanation, is not great.

Comment: You've been here for 5 years, you should know better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundary at start and a negative lookahead regex after 3 digits:

```
\b\d{3}(?!\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU6nO6/1)

`(?!\d)` is zero width assertion that will also allow a word boundary or end of line or any other non-digit after 3 digits.